# What is the domain of a division of functions?

Tags: functions, combinations, real-numbers

This question is about **real** functions of **real** variables.

I think that, in general, if the domain of some function $f(x)$ is A, and the domain of another function $g(x)$ is B, then the domain of $(f/g)(x)$ is A$\cap$B and where $g\neq0$.

Now, what happens if I have something like $f(x)=2$, $g(x)=1/x$? In this case, $(f/g)(x)=2x$, which seems to be defined for all real numbers. But my statement above (which I think is correct in general) implies that $x=0$ is not allowed. So I'm conflicted.

Can somebody tell me what the domain of $(f/g)(x)$ is in this case? Is it all real numbers, or all real numbers except $0$?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. If I have a function $f$ that is only defined for $x=6$ and another one ($g$) only defined for $x=3$, then $(f/g)$ is not defined anywhere. I don't see the problem with that.

Comment: I agree with the first answer given, which reiterates your second sentence. This will clear up your 3rd block of text: $2/(1/x)$ and $2x$ are different functions. So if I give you the function $2x$, then that's that. And if I give you the function $2/(1/x)$, that's good too. They aren't the same. But if I give you $2x$ _and_ tell you I want the domain to be all reals minus $0$, now the two functions are the same. Without stating the domain, it's implied $2x$ is over all the reals. I could have told you that $2x$ is over the domain $6 < x \leq 7$, or whatever else

Comment: The domain of $f/g$ excludes $0$ based on the definition of $f/g$ you gave.  But do not take this too seriously.  Math is about communication of ideas more than definitions, so if it is inconvenient to exclude $0$, you can "fill it in" - as long as you do this in a way that is completely clear to yourself and whoever else is interested in your work.

Comment: This is correct if you think about them as functions in the set-theoretic sense. But for sufficiently well-behaved families of functions (rational, analytic) you can actually ignore those singularities and it makes perfect sense, even if *pointwise* you have silly stuff like division by zero. Or, if you treat them as functions on a measurable space, you can ignore what happens on a set of measure $0$, and that's fine, too. In each case, you can think of dividing *equivalence classes* of functions, rather than actual functions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your mistake is in thinking that
$$\frac2{1/x}\quad\hbox{and}\quad 2x$$
are **always** equal.  They're not.  To carefully prove that they are equal, we have
$$\frac2{1/x}=\frac2{1/x}\,1=\frac2{1/x}\frac xx=\frac{2x}1=2x\ .$$
But this is not correct when $x=0$, because $\frac00$ is not equal to $1$.  So we have to consider $x=0$ separately.  In that case we have $2x=0$, but
$$\frac2{1/x}=\frac2{1/0}=\frac2{\hbox{nonsense}}=\hbox{nonsense}\ .$$
So in your example, the domain of $f/g$ must exclude $0$.

Comment: I loved your answer; super simple and clear. Great name too, btw.

Comment: @DavidS: Unfortunately, this answer is wrong. mfl's answer is correct. The error is that "$\frac2{1/x}$" is **not even defined** when $x = 0$, simply because "$1/x$" is not defined when $x = 0$. One **cannot** manipulate expressions as if they are defined, when they are actually not.

Comment: @user21820 Basically, that's exactly what I said in my answer.  What did you think I meant by "$\frac2{1/0}=\cdots=\hbox{nonsense}$"?  Just asking.

Comment: @David: I object to your explanation, especially the way it implies that the problem is that "$0/0$ is not equal to $1$". But that is not the real problem. "$1/x$" and anything containing it is already meaningless (or syntactically malformed, or a type error) if $x = 0$. For the same reason, your second chain of equalities is not mathematical equalities, but rather reductions. In particular, the correct reasoning is that for "$\frac2{1/x}$" to be well-defined we must have "$1/x$" well-defined, which requires $x \ne 0$. Note the use of quotes to distinguish expressions from values.

Comment: `Your second chain of equalities is not mathematical equalities` - well of course not, and that is exactly my point.  The problem that many beginners have is that they think $0/0$ is equal to $1$.  Any question on this site needs to be answered on a level appropriate to the question, and judging by the OP's comment, I have successfully done that.

Comment: `meaningless (or syntactically malformed, or a type error)` - in other words, nonsense.  Exactly as I have said.

Answer (score 6):

If the domain of $f$ is $A$ and the domain of $g$ is $B$ then the domain of $f/g$ is $$A\cap B\setminus\{x:B|g(x)\ne 0\}.$$ (Of course, we must assume that $A\cap B\setminus\{x:B|g(x)\ne 0\}\ne \emptyset$. In other case $f/g$ doesn't make sense.)

In your example, $f(x)=2$ and $g(x)=1/x.$ We have that

$$\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}=2x, \forall x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}.$$ Why? Note that $g(0)$ doesn't exist. So we can't consider

$$\dfrac{f(0)}{g(0)}.$$

Answer (score 0):

It is all real numbers without zero i think.
Check out this similar example:
$$F(x)=\dfrac{(x-2)(x-1)}{(x-2)}$$
You can simplify this fraction to $F(x)=(x-1)$ ONLY when 2 is excluded from the domain
So we say that $F$ is defined $$\forall x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{2\}.$$ 
Even though $F(x)=(x-1)$

Answer (score 0):

Usually you define division of functions $f:A\to\mathbb R$ and $g:B\to\mathbb R$ as pointwise division, that is,
$$(f/g)(x)=f(x)/g(x),$$
which obviously is only defined where $g(x)\ne 0$. Therefore the domain of the quotient is $D=\{x\in A\cap B\mid x\ne 0\}$.

However while this is the common choice, it is not the *only* possible choice. Another possible choice for continuous functions might be to define $f/g$ as
$$(f/g)(x) = \lim_{y\to x} f(y)/g(y)$$
with the domain being all points in $\mathbb R$ where this limit exists.

With that definition and $f(x)=2$ (with domain $\mathbb R$) and $g(x)=1/x$ (with domain $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$), you would indeed find that $(f/g)(x) = 2x$ with domain $\mathbb R$.